# WPF: Binding to Custom UserControl from imported ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, import, viewmodel

Ok, I know what the problem is I just don't know the best to fix it...

I have a Custom WPF UserControl that is a DoB picker which has a dependencyproperty called (wait for it...) SelectedDoB. I have a View that uses this DoBPicker and creates a binding on the SelectedDoB property to a DoB property in the ViewModel/Views DataContext. This binding is defined in the XAML.

Here's the problem - the ViewModel is imported and isn't assigned to the DataContext until the OnImportsSatisfied but by that point the DoB picker has already been constructed and tried to bind to the non existent property in DataContext/ViewModel.

I could simply instantiate the ViewModel in the Views constructor but that would be to easy.

Does anyone have any other suggestions while still instantiating the ViewModel via the Import attribute.

Thank you!

Comment: not sure I understand your problem but satisfying imports on a view sound odd to me.
do you just need a way to call a full notify property changed so the binding would work?

Comment: That could be my problem. I may be implementing this the wrong way. Is it not standard practice to import a viewmodel? I'm sure I saw an example doing just that - might be wrong. Some further reading is required I think.